# Query to display all classes and all predicates of DBpedia

Tags: semantics, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

How to display all classes and all predicates of DBpedia using sparql in dbpedia.org/snorql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * { ?x a owl:Class }
```

and:

```
SELECT * { ?x a rdf:Property }
```

I don't know if these are *all* classes/properties.

Comment: That ought to work, but I might suggest including rdfs:Class & the OWL properties.  I don't recall if they're used in dbpedia or not, but they're worth including.